# How to find sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{1}{n^2}$

Tags: analysis, summation, uniform-convergence

Probably using uniform convergence - I'm looking for $f(0)$, where
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{\cos(\frac{x}{n})} {n^2}$$

Comment: Related [$\sum 1/n^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).

Comment: You can get the proper font and spacing for $\cos$ using `\cos`. For operators that don't have a command of their own you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function.

Answer (score 4):

It's well known that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
We have that: 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n)^2}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$$

and that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n)^2}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$$

See if you can use these  to obtain your result